# Why do some npm packages have an es directory?

Tags: javascript, npm

I've noticed some libraries have duplicated code in an es folder. Why do developers do that?

examples:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I presume they use a transpiler to produce code for legacy runtimes. It might be easier to determine if you name at least one library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developers can ship their packages in a few different flavours, depending on how the user (e.g. you) wants to use them.

If you want to use the module code (i.e. import), or you want to use es2015 (i.e. the require), or you even might want to use it in a browser environment (standalone - think .min file).

The folders names are meaningless, developers can call them whatever they want, but they'll probably put their non-transpiled (i.e. import) modules in an es or esm directory

Keep in mind that just because you are "import"-ing their module doesn't mean that their module uses imports. Most nowadays are still transpiled before being shipped so the code you're `import`-ing is probably `require`-ing stuff.

It's kind of complicated...

Comment: Ah - so to confirm my understanding:

If your publishing a library that will be supported by users not running something like babel, you need to provide the files in a number of patterns?

Comment: @RossKinsella - you, as a publisher, can provide whatever you want. Publishers want their packages out there to be consumable by everyone, so they tend to transpile it for "older" ES5 systems. They can choose to just provide the ES5 (i.e. `require`) because they are still consumable by your code if you "import" them. Or they can provide you the es6 (i.e. "import") code. The JS ecosystem, as everyone knows is ridiculously messy and constantly evolving, but that's why I think everybody loves it.